# Binding data from harddrive in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps

*using c#, VS 2013, Windows Store App*

I have some Json file with inforamtion about some event, in this file user can store some data, and one of this data - path to image for event, example:

```
{"Events":
[
  {
    "UniqueId": "Day-1-Item-1",
    "Name": "Item Title: 1",
    "Place": "Item Subtitle: 1",
    "Description": "Event 1",
    "Start" : "2,25,2014,2,14",
    "End" : "2,25,2014,16,44",
    "ImagePath" : "Assets/appbar.calendar.png"
  },
  {
    "UniqueId": "Day-1-Item-2",
    "Name": "Item Title: 1",
    "Place": "Item Subtitle: 1",
    "Description": "Event 1",
    "Start" : "2,25,2014,2,14",
    "End" : "2,25,2014,16,44",
    "ImagePath" : "D:\\Pictures\\Abstract\\8.jpg"
  }
]
```

}

So i bind all this information to UI (using XAML) and got something like on pic below:

[image]

So, for thoose items where i put pic from Assets folder in project (mean `"ImagePath" : "Assets/appbar.calendar.png"`) i got correct result (on pic it's calendar), but for events, where i choose pic from harddrive - i got nothing.

**Question**: Are it's possible to bind UI to data from HardDrive? or I need to create some copy of pic at assets folder (or in `LocalState` folder) of App?

---

EDIT

So now i have next:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string filePath = value.ToString(); //get path to picture
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(); //create bitmap image blank

        if (filePath.Contains("Assets")) //if standart picture
        {
            return LoadImageFromAssetsLibrary(image);
        }
        else
        {
            return LoadImageFromString(image, filePath);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private async Task<ImageSource> LoadImageFromString(BitmapImage image, string path)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary; //get folder
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path); //find and read file
        //set source of file to image
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }

        return ...// i dont know how to return ImageSource from image that i create in code above
    }
```

So i a little bit stack - How to return ImageSource from image, try `(ImageSource)image` but got (targetType - ImageSource):

[image]

---

EDIT 2

After small changes (from last updates), got that pic from app folders can be showed with Converter, but from pic library - no - think problem is with access...

[image]

Changed :

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string filePath = value.ToString(); //get path to picture
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(); //create bitmap image blank
        if (filePath.Contains("Assets")) //if standart picture
        {
            LoadImageFromAssetsLibrary(image, filePath);
            return image;
        }
        else
        {
            LoadImageFromString(image, filePath);
            return image;
        }
    }
    //for this method required access
    private async Task LoadImageFromString(BitmapImage image, string path)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary; //get folder
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path); //find and read file
        //set source of file to image
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }
    }
    //this work correctly
    private async Task LoadImageFromAssetsLibrary(BitmapImage image, string path)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("ms-appx:///");
        builder.Append(path);
        string localPath = builder.ToString();

        Uri requestedFileUri = new Uri(localPath); //set default folder
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(requestedFileUri); //read file
        //set source of file to image
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }
    }
```

Also, i allow access to pic folder:

[image]

---

EDIT3

[image]

Comment: For a simple image like that, ditch the pic/image file and convert it to xaml for a template and throw it in your resources.

Comment: its just a sample, image can be anyone that user can pick for example selected (that not showed) its a photo

Comment: I think you should make a copy about the user selected images. Maybe you can play with default Images folder, possible can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different places that you can access with or without user permission (which is what you are asking). First, I'll give an explanation, then I'll give an Answer. Skip to the Answer section if you wish.

### Locations Accessible Without User Permission

---

### Read

- Install Folder
- Roaming Data Folder
- Local Data Folder
- [Settings] (Technically you just write values, but still worth listing)

### Write

- Roaming Data Folder
- Local Data Folder
- [Settings]

---

---

### Locations Accessible When Declared in Your App Manifest (Capabilities)

---

### Read/Write

[Known Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders)

- Music Library
- Documents Library
- Pictures Library
- Videos Library
- Removable Storage

**All other files you must directly ask the user to select for you.** You do this using the `FileOpenPicker` or the `FolderPicker` classes. You can then store these objects in the [`FutureAccessList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207457), which will allow future use.

---

---

### Answer

---

**If**

- the folder in question is in the `Pictures Library` (if the you or the user have Included it in their library manually in the case of `D:\Pictures\...`),

**and**

- you have included access to the pictures library in your `App Manifest`'s `Capabilities`.

Then you can indeed 'bind' to those files.

### To 'Bind' the Files

Create an `IValueConverter`. This converter will accept a path string, parse it to find the filename and location in the Pictures library, and the access the Pictures Library using `KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary`.

This is an `async` process. The converter cannot be asynchronous, so the basic process will be like so:

### In the Converter

- Parse the image, making sure it is correct.
- Create a blank `BitmapImage` object.
- Pass the string and the `BitmapImage` into an async `LoadImageFromString` method

### In the `LoadImageFromString` Method

- Retrieve the `StorageFolder` in question from `KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary`.
- Find the file.
- Optional: Retrieve the file Thumbnail.
- Optional: Set the `Source` (using `BitmapImage.SetSource`) of the passed `BitmapImage` parameter to the thumbnail.
- Read in the file (`await`).
- Set the `Source` (using `BitmapImage.SetSource`) of the `BitmapImage` parameter to the contents of the file, decoding them using a `BitmapDecoder` if necessary.

You will now asynchronously load in the data from your ViewModel (which should be parsing your JSON), finding the data in question, and setting the source of your `Image` control to its contents.

---

---

### Last Note

If this is not an app designed for users and all of your images are in that one folder, you can also just have your app store an access point to that folder manually and retrieve all images from there. This is obviously not a suggested method for consumer-driven applications, but can be done.

Edit: Given your example above, here is what you are missing. There may be some additional work needed in getting the file reading to work from this example (using the `BitmapDecoder` as mentioned above), but there may also not.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    string filePath = value.ToString(); //get path to picture
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(); //create bitmap image blank

    if (filePath.Contains("Assets")) //if standart picture
    {
        // Have it start processing the image in the background
        LoadImageFromAssetsLibrary(image);
        // Return the image. Even though it may not be done processing,
        // When it's done, it will fill the image with the source automatically
        return image;
    }
    else
    {
        // Same as above
        LoadImageFromString(image, filePath);
        return image;
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private async Task LoadImageFromString(BitmapImage image, string path)
{
    StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary; //get folder
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path); //find and read file
    //set source of file to image
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }

    // You don't need to return anything here. It is in effect using the 'image'
    // reference as an 'out' variable, and filling it with the data retrieved.
}
```

Comment: thanks for so good answer - allow to understand me even more. Now try to create described.. i'll will post all that i code

Comment: Added the fixes to your example in my answer

Comment: If you're just using the straight path from the example, then you're not following the advice I gave. You don't give it an absolute path, you query the folder. If your pictures library includes D:/Pictures, and the picture is D:/Pictures/MyPicts/pic.png, then you have to [Query for the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br227274).

Comment: I found problem - in Json file i left old path like `D:\\Pictures\\Abstract\\8.jpg`. Now i clear file and add new items, so the path to file is like `"ImagePath":"111.jpg" ` - mean in pic folder and "ImagePath":"Assets/appbar.calendar.png" - mean Install Folder. Thanks for replay - i'll check file again and found this mistake. so now it's ok - you can see print in edit3